# Scapy RA flag showing although port http is open (80)

Tags: python, tcp, port, flags

I have made a program with Scapy that checks for open ports and for some reason when I check for port 80 for example (scan other computer's port) it says it's closed (RA instead of SA) why is that??
or maybe I have confused SA and RA?

```
import sys
i, o, e = sys.stdin, sys.stdout,  sys.stderr
from scapy.all import *
sys.stdin, sys.stdout, sys.stderr = i, o, e
TARGET_IP = '192.168.1.150'


def main():
   packet1 = sr1(IP(dst=TARGET_IP)/TCP(dport=80, seq=123, flags="S"), timeout=1, verbose=0)
   packet1.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and the output is

```
###[ TCP ]### 
 sport     = http
 dport     = ftp_data
 seq       = 0
 ack       = 124
 dataofs   = 5L
 reserved  = 0L
 flags     = RA
 window    = 0
 chksum    = 0x2aef
 urgptr    = 0
 options   = {}
```

What am I doing incorrect that makes this port closed? I have opened the chrome browser in the other computer and I'm guessing it should work...
Thanks for any help!

Comment: It seems like I'm not supposed to see port 80 open since it's server sided, but spiceworks.com tells me none of the ports are open, how would I open ANY port to check?

Comment: This example works fine for me. Does the problem reproduce for any publicly available IP?

Comment: It's all good, at the end it did work my port was actually not open somehow